# apache webService sending XML and Not JSon

Tags: xml, json, apache

i'm currently developping an iphone application that uses a database in an external server. On this server, the db is manipulated by Java on Apache.

The webService is working great, but impossible to get some JSon Data.

What is the kind of the url i have to call in order to havec json data ?
The current url is like : http://localihost:8080/covoiturage-rest/user/profile/toto

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests may have an `Accept` header with the MIME type of the content they wish to receive.  So, if you want XML, you would set the `Accept` header to `application/xml`; if you want JSON you would set it to `application/json`.  A request that doesn't contain this header is assumed to want an HTML response.

That said, you can set the `Accept` header, but you'll only receive JSON if the web service supports returning JSON.  Some web services will return JSON, some will return only XML.  If you specify a MIME type that the server can't provide you should receive a 406 (Not Acceptable).